# Yii Blog demo, rating system not updating database when rated

Tags: php, mysql, yii, blogs

I'm trying to add a simple rating system to Yii's demo blog. I added a Rating model with an id, value, post id, and user id.

I added an addRating() method to my Post model:

```
public function addRating($rating)
{
    $rating->post_id=$this->id;
    $rating->user_id=Yii::app()->user->getId();
}
```

I also added a newRating() method to PostController:

```
protected function newRating($post)
{
    $rating = new Rating;

    if(isset($_POST['Rating']))
    {
        $rating->attributes=$_POST['Rating'];
        if($post->addRating($rating))
        {
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('ratingSubmitted', 'Thanks for your rating!');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    return $rating;
}
```

I updated the Post view to render the rating form:

```
<div class="form">

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'rating-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    )); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'val'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'val',array(1,2,3,4,5)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'val'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>
<br/>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

However, when I select a rating from the dropdown menu and hit submit on the Post view page, it is not inserted into the tbl_rating table. Am I missing an essential step here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The rating model isn't saved in either of the methods. Also how are you calling the `newRating()`?

Comment: where is you have called to save to database rating. if it is your full code for saving rating. then u have to to create action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your rating in the DB! In the code you showed, nowhere you save the `ActiveRecord` object `$rating`.

You should do something like:

```
public function addRating($rating)
{
    $rating->post_id=$this->id;
    $rating->user_id=Yii::app()->user->getId();
    if($rating->save()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I realized I was missing a return statement in my addRating() function. I got it working though. Thanks!